# How to get exactly 2 digits after the decimal point in sage

Tags: python, sage, approximation

How to get exactly 2 digits after the decimal point approx in sage?
If I do the following:

```
sage: k = 0.0006
sage: k.n(digits = 2)
0.00060
```

I get too many digits. In this case I would want 0.00 as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Python formatting makes it easy to print floats with two decimal digits.

So we can turn `k` into a Python float and use Python string formatting.

```
sage: k = 0.00060
sage: print('{:0.2f}'.format(float(k)))
0.00

sage: k = 1234.5
sage: print('{:0.2f}'.format(float(k)))
1234.50
```

In Python3-based SageMath, one can even use f-strings:

```
sage: print(f'{float(k):0.2f}')
1234.50
```